# Word Interop: ScrollIntoView fails on a newly-opened document

Tags: .net, ms-word, office-interop

I'm opening a Word document (a User Guide), iterating through the paragraphs until I find the one I want, then scrolling the window to that paragraph (ie. "contextual" help.)

The problem I'm having is that the `ScrollIntoView` method appears to do nothing for that brief period of time while Word is rendering the newly-opened document.

Code excerpt:

```
var wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref filename, ref confirmConversions, ref readOnly, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref visible, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph paragraph in wordDoc.Paragraphs)
{
    var text = paragraph.Range.Text;
    if (text == headingToScrollTo + "\r")
    {
        wordDoc.ActiveWindow.ScrollIntoView(paragraph.Range);
        break;
    }
}
```

Currently I have inserted a `Thread.Sleep(500)` before the `ScrollIntoView` method call. Obviously this is a pretty horrible and brittle solution. A proper way of waiting for the document to be fully rendered before scrolling would be much better.

Comment: I'm really not sure if my idea will solve the problem you have but you could check it. **You could try to select the appropriate paragraph range instead of scrolling view into that.** If you don't want to select the whole paragraph you could select position just before that paragraph to achieve quite similar result to scrolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to KazJaw! Instead of `wordDoc.ActiveWindow.ScrollIntoView(paragraph.Range);` use `paragraph.Range.Select();`

I also made it scroll 45 lines downward after that because selecting the paragraph will only scroll it into view at the bottom of the window.

```
paragraph.Range.Select();
object linesToScroll = 45;
wordDoc.ActiveWindow.SmallScroll(ref linesToScroll, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
```